# Changing TIME_FORMAT for locale

Tags: python, django, localization

According to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#time-format):

> if USE_L10N is set to True, then the locale-dictated format has higher
>   precedence and will be applied instead

First of all I would like to know where this locale-dicated format is defined and if there is any possibility to customize it somewhere for a given locale?

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7//topics/i18n/formatting/)

> When it’s enabled, two users accessing the same content may see dates, times and numbers formatted in different ways, depending on the formats for their current locale.

so this is something that targets the audience/client (ie. if I am accessing the website in New York, I will get my time in EST, vs you may get your time in GMT in London)

Comment: well i see, so that is actually not the thing i am looking for. currently in the project i a maintaining the people used the trick described here: https://github.com/DNX/django-simple-project/wiki/Translate-strings-in-settings.py and just defined the time format in the according locale files. was just wodering if there is a more elegant way (i am not to happy to have settings overwritten in the locale files as it is very confusing / hard to find and incompatible with standard django behaviour)